# Change event time label in agendaWeek (FullCalendar)

Tags: fullcalendar

I change event time label using this code:

```
eventRender: function (event, element,view) {
    element.find('.fc-time').text(event.start.format('hh:mm a') + ' - ' + event.end.format('hh:mm a'));
},
```

It will diplayed like : `08:00 am - 09:00 am`. It worked but only in month view. When I switch to agendaWeek view, It will display like : `8:0008:00 am - 09:00 am-`. How do I make it works in both views? I try to hide the front time but it will hide all.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the displayed time format for all views [using `timeFormat`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/).  To get the end time also displayed, you need to [set `displayEventEnd`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventEnd/), as it defaults to false.

```
timeFormat: 'h:mm t',
displayEventEnd: true
```